# Creating paypal buttons on the fly

Tags: paypal

I have a webapp, where users sell printing services,  I want to allow my users to add a pay now buttons to their pages so customers can pay for their services.

My users specify their paypal email address etc in the settings and set up their services with a price etc.

What API should I use to create the pay now buttons on the fly ?

Thanks

Comment: Paypal API of course but your question lacks detail about what kind of system you are using. Is it some kind of CMS or a custom website.

Comment: A custom website. I want to create a encrypted button for the users page, so their customers can make payments. I think the Adaptive Payments API is the one I need?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an API for creating "pay now" buttons. You can either create the button from within your customer's Paypal accounts or dynamically generate with HTML (see [HTML Variables for Paypal Payments standard](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)).

One advantage of creating the buttons from your/their Paypal account is that you can get an additional layer of security (support for encrypting the form or using a hosted button id so user cannot change the amount submitted to Paypal).

However, if you deal with hundreds of different buttons then it makes more sense to dynamically generate the buttons and just perform additional validation when Paypal sends back the confirmation (either through [PDT or IPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836779/paypal-ipn-vs-pdt)) before shipping your items.

Comment: I would use PayPal's API for creating buttons, especially creating buttons dynamically with hidden price fields, as the price fields are hackable. With the API, you can request an encrypted HTML button that cannot be tampered with.

Answer (score 3):

You could use PayPal's [JavaScriptButtons API](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons) and create your buttons dynamically with:

```
paypal.button.create(business, data, config, parentNode)
```

Comment: assuming this uses the Button manager API, it may be worth pointing out that the button manager API has been depreceated https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/examples/

Answer (score 0):

There is an button manager API that let's you create secure buttons - here is more info: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/button-manager

Comment: Link does not load

Comment: the button manager API has been depreceated https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/examples/

Answer (score -1):

PayPal offers different buttons based on your requirement.
Follow these steps to generate PayPal button:

1. Login to your PayPal Account
2. Click on Tools --> All Tools
3. Click on PayPal buttons

Now you are given few button options --> Buy Now is one if them.

Follow those three steps and then copy the code at the end of 3 steps and paste it in the page where you want this button to appear.

You are good to take Payments!

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to create buttons on the fly.