# Is there any way to get the transaction details from PayPal in the return page for php?

Tags: php, paypal

- I am using a PayPal sandbox for testing the PayPal payment. On success payment of the bill it is returning to the success page. But i am not getting any transaction details in the return page. Can anyone suggest any way to resolve this?
- Is there any way to get the Transaction details from PayPal return page as POST?

Comment: I think that will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434937/get-information-from-paypal-after-a-transaction

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PayPal Standard buttons, you can use [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/).
Just specify the return URL in `return` parameter and PDT will return the transaction information.  You will also need to [enable Auto-Return](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside) in your PayPal account.

If you are using Express checkout, after the Doexpresscheckout is complete, you will get all the necessary information including transaction information in response. alternatively, call the [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API to get the transaction information.

Also, if not in the return page, you can always use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to get the transaction details which is asynchronous.  This is actually the recommended way to do any post-transaction processing you may need to do because it will allow you to correctly handle pending payments that may not clear for a few days.