# Mechanism to store a session variable during Paypal IPN transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've looked for hours for an workable answer to this without any luck so here is my question/issue:

I have a page with a form that has a Paypal generated Pay Now button with a drop down with 3 choices.  The user clicks on one of the three choices which are priced $7, $14 and $20.  The user is paying for a service and after paying on the Paypal site they will be uploading 1, 2 or 3 files depending on their choice.

I need a way to capture the choice so I can send them to one of 3 pages.  I think I understand the the normal $_SESSION variable won't work when using Paypal according to this answer: [Get information from PayPal after a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434937/get-information-from-paypal-after-a-transaction)

I still don't understand what the proper way to do this is.  What method is recommended?  Should I use a DB to store the transaction data and then in the return page read back the data?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just like in the answer you linked to above, note the distinction between `IPN` and `PDT`. The former, `IPN` is **not** visited by any human (e.g. your customer/buyer), your `return_url` is where PayPal sends your customer/buyer. Your `return_url` is **not** your `IPN` url. That hopefully should help clarify the answer by EJP below...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capture session information to accomplish this. You can just set the `return_url` variable accordingly in the form. You can also add arguments to the URL to transmit context.

Comment: I'm a little slow so please excuse my lack of understanding.  But if you can clarify your answer a bit.  Can I dynamically modify the return_url?  I need to be able to send the user to one of three different pages depending on what amount they clicked on.