# Paypal Sandbox not returning any variables

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have my code as follows:

```
    $paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; 
    $paypal_id = 'payments@business.com';

    $str .= "<form method='post' action='".$paypal_url."'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='business' value='".$paypal_id."'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Room'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='".getRoom($id)."'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='amount' id='paypal_cost' value='".getBal($id)."'>";
    $str .= "<input name='notify_url' value='http://localhost/tropicana/guests/notify.php' type='hidden'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/tropicana/guests/payments.php'>";
    $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/tropicana/guests/notify.php'>";
    $str .= "<button type='submit' name='submit' class='form-control btn-danger'>Pay $".getBal($id)." with <i>PayPal</i>";

    $str .= "</form>";
```

But after a successful payment, my return script `notify.php` is not receiving any variables.

When i try to `print_r()` the `$_REQUEST`, it returns an empty array.

Comment: After transaction complete is redirecting on notify.php?

Comment: Yes its returning to that script

Comment: and the print_r($_REQUEST); getting empty array right?

Comment: Yes it is. It's empty

Comment: Check this [Paypal response] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434937/get-information-from-paypal-after-a-transaction) [possiblly duplicate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Your `notify_url` cannot be *localhost* since PayPal will send you the IPN messages (from outside), which means your development machine must be exposed to internet.

One way to expose your computer is using a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com), or something like [serveo](http://serveo.net), or similar.
Once you do that, set your **notify_url** to that public URL to receive the IPN messages.

But, be warned:

- if you use free ngrok option, your random subdomain (ex. 13bf0ee2.ngrok.com) will change on every ngrok re/start
- if you test subscriptions, your previously created plans with ngrok notify_url won't be valid anymore and you will not receive the recurrent IPN messages.
- because PayPal sandbox is one big piece of junk, you may not receive IPN messages **at all** simply because they are totally broken service.

Of course, you will scratch your head sometimes why things worked yesterday and not today. The best option is to boycott them and move on with your life and business with someone who's actually competent on this field.